# C# Entity Framework: Perform operation out of transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I'm using EF database transaction:

```
using (var transaction = DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
     ....//some processing
     OrderRepository.AddOrUpdate(order);
     task.ordersProcessed++;
     BackgroundTaskRepository.Update(task);
     ....//
}
```

I want to update task status, but as it's wrapped in transaction the cahnges are not applied to the database untill all processing is complete. Both Repositories using the same DbContext.

EF does not support parallel transactions, so wrapping BackgroundTaskRepository call into another transaction causes exception.

Is there a way to call `BackgroundTaskRepository.Update` "out of transaction" without creating a new DbContext?

Comment: Any reason you cannot rely on just using SaveChanges as the transaction service as a whole? EF doesn't do any writing to your db until that is called. Admittedly there are certainly times where you need to implement a full transaction but that may not be the case in this scenario.

Comment: SaveChanges will save all the data. I need to push Orders data to the  database only if all activities in the transaction were complete and also I need to track background task progress (BackgroundTaskRepository) to show the progress to a user. But the progress (Task) will not be changed untill the transaction is commited.
For now I ended up with creating an OnProgress event and second DbContext. But I still wonder if there is a way without creating separate DbContext.